# Embedding Redux framework with theme

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I have embedded Redux framework in my theme as it is shown in this example
[Embedding Redux into Your Theme or Plugin](https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/advanced/embedding-redux-into-your-theme-or-plugin/)

Now when my theme is finished and when i checked it with Theme Check plugin, it shows me errors in Redux Core folder. 
What should i do because i want to upload my theme to wordpress.org?

Answer (score 0):

You store whole redux file in your theme directory that why your theme get error from Theme Check plugin. So you have no need to put all redux file in your theme. Just copy the sample-config.php and rename it what you want and include the file in your theme. Now you can write all redux related code in here. Before start writing code, just check redux plugin exist or not with following code.

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Redux' ) ) {
    return;
}
```